# Cannot configure javafx in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx

I've been trying to make javafx work with vscode for a while, even though i follow the official javafx guide: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-java (vscode instructions on the left).

I use linux mint 21 and have jdk 17 installed.

The project is a folder `HelloFX` with `bin`,`lib`,`src` folders inside.
Inside `src` i have `hellofx` folder containing:

`App.java`

```
    package hellofx;


    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class App extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("hellofx.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(App.class);
        }
    }
```

`Controller.java`

```
    private Label label;

    public void initialize() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        label.setText("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + "\nRunning on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        }
    }
```

`hellofx.fxml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>


    <StackPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"                                   minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com /javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="hellofx.Controller">
        <children>
            <Label fx:id="label" text="Label" />
        </children>
    </StackPane>
```

As instrucions i create a `launch.json`

```
    {

    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    {
        "type": "java",
        "name": "Launch App",
        "request": "launch",
        "mainClass": "hellofx.App",
        "vmArgs": "--module-path ~/Scaricati/javafx-sdk-21/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",
        }
    ]
 }
```

Plus i write in the `.bashrc` file:

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-oracle`

There must be something important missing, since the application doesn't run:

```
    App.java:3: error: package javafx.application does not exist
    import javafx.application.Application;
    ^
    App.java:4: error: package javafx.fxml does not exist
    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
    ^
    App.java:5: error: package javafx.scene does not exist
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    ^
    App.java:6: error: package javafx.scene does not exist
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    ^
    App.java:7: error: package javafx.stage does not exist
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    ^
    App.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
    public class App extends Application {
    ^
    symbol: class Application
    App.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    ^
    symbol: class Stage
    location: class App
    App.java:11: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    u/Override
    ^
    App.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("hellofx.fxml"));
    ^
    symbol: class Parent
    location: class App
    App.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("hellofx.fxml"));
    ^
    symbol: variable FXMLLoader
    location: class App
    App.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("hellofx.fxml"));
    ^
    symbol: method getClass()
    location: class App
    App.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 300));
    ^
    symbol: class Scene
    location: class App
    App.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    launch(App.class);
    ^
    symbol: method launch(Class<App>)
    location: class App
    13 errors
```

**EDIT**

The application runs fine with this method:

https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular

But there's the downside of having the console cluttered with errors although the app will run with the commands

Comment: In the instructions you referenced, probably you didn’t perform properly the non-modular in the VSCode IDE step titled “2. Add JavaFX dependencies”, which adds the JavaFX libraries as dependencies to your project.

Comment: @jewelsea i did add the javafx jars to the reference library

Answer (score 0):

Why the hell are you using Visual Studio Code for this? Well you can, but can use screws with a hammer too.

I recommend you:

**Step 1:**

Download the forever free Community Version of IntelliJ here:
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/?section=linux

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

**Step 2:**

Install it, click on file > new project > JavaFX project > create.

**Step 3:**

Profit, because everything works out of the box. And everybody can help you.